# Difference between two prototype setting code in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

There are two piece of javascript code samples.
1-st code is:

```
var child1 = new Parent1();
child1.prototype = Object.create(Parent1);
```

2-nd code is:

```
var child2 = new Parent2();
child2.prototype = Object.create(Parent2.prototype);
```

So could you tell me please, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - `.prototype` - is a property of constructor (e.g. function) not object. It means, all objects created with your constructor will have `constructor prototype property` as `prototype` :)

To set prototype of created object, you can use [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property or [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) method, but be aware, that both are part of new ES2015 standard, which is not fully supported by all browsers.

Your code corrected will look like this

```
var child1 = new Parent1();
Object.setPrototypeOf(child1, Object.create(Parent1));
//vs
var child2 = new Parent2();
Object.setPrototypeOf(child2, Object.create(Parent2.prototype));
```

Difference is in 1st case you're setting `Function object` as prototype, which is kind of meaningless because it will contain only default function object porperties. In second one you're setting constructor's prototype as a prototype of constructed object, which is meaningless too, because it's already set after constructing.

**Main part:** code you've posted is not really correct and not commonly used. Prototypal inheritance should be used different. To know how, you can read answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

*Interesting part*: your code is still valid javascript, but it will do not work as you expected, because it's not working with prototypal inheritance.